# How to suggest on a score that the dynamics are meant to be inconsistent?

Tags: piano, notation

[image: Imgur]

I'm trying to get a drone-like sound on the bass that relies on relatively inconsistent dynamics for effect. I added "a resilient and ominous drone" to suggest that it's meant to appear to reduce itself only to keep coming back, but I don't want a strict structure for it.

I notated some variations with the accents but what I really want to say is "vary the dynamics as preferred while keeping it around piano overall".

An example can be heard [here](https://soundcloud.com/patrunjelunecro/drone-example/s-3T883).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't think of a single marking that will do this; you'll likely just want to have text clarifying what you want the performer(s) to do. Options like:

> Vary the dynamics randomly while staying within the *piano* range.

But for what it's worth, I felt like your recording exceeded the *piano* dynamic range. Maybe something like:

> Randomly change the dynamic level of each pitch, keeping the dynamics between *pp* and *mp*.

You may also want to consider the following addition

> Randomly change the dynamic level *and strength of articulation* of each pitch, keeping the dynamics between *pp* and *mp*.

Plenty of other options exist, of course.

And I really like your description of "a resilient and ominous drone," but I'm not sure I would have read into it enough to play it as if it were "meant to appear to reduce itself only to keep coming back." If I were a performer, I'd be more than happy to see that indication written in, as well!

Comment: Perhaps something like *vary dynamics ad lib.* also. And check out Penderecki scores to see how he specified random variations.